# Google App Engine Scheduled Tasks Billing

Tags: google-app-engine

The GAE documentation states "Free applications can have up to 20 scheduled tasks. Paid applications can have up to 100 scheduled tasks.".  I need to run more that 20 scheduled tasks however I can't find any details on charges for the scheduled tasks - are we billed specifically by number of tasks beyond the free quota?

Answer (score 1):

It is talking about cron job not taskqueue. And it's not the number of tasks you executed, but the number of cron job endpoint. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

Comment: Cron jobs is what I mean i.e. <cron> entries

Comment: you can aggregate them by hit one cron endpoint and then spin multiple tasks.

Comment: Yes, I can do that and have a longer term refactor plan to reduce the number of cron jobs required.  In terms of the initial questions, does anyone know if you are billed specifically for the number of cron jobs you have above the 20 free?

Comment: It's a limitation. I believe you're not billed based on the number of cron jobs you have.